# Permission denied when cloning firebase config

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I recently decided to create a staging project for my app using `firebase use --add`. I am attempting to clone environment configurations from one project to the new staging project `firebase functions:config:clone --from prod`

I keep getting a 403 error, specifically `Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied on resource project prod.` I'm really not sure why I'm getting this error as I have **owner** level permission for both projects. Can you please point me to what I may have missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was getting the error because I was trying to clone config using project alias. I was able to solve this by using the project id.

Comment: Cna you please help me out with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77163103/firebase-deploying-multiple-sites-to-different-environmentsprojects

I want to create different environments. I have just created empty projects from the console.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a [IAM permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/permissions). Be sure that the `User` or `Service Account` has enough permissions to perform the action.

Here is the list of [product- category predefined roles](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-category). Please be sure to follow always the least privilege principle.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Yes, I'm sure it's something to do with IAM permissions, I'm just a bit confused because I've got owner role for both projects. Any pointers to what can be done to fix this, please?

Comment: 1. Are you using the same user in both projects? 2. I checked the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#use_environment_configuration_to_initialize_a_module) and it seems this process does not need an API to be enabled. Given this, could you please confirm is the same user?

Comment: I suppose I am, my personal gmail is signed into firebase cli.

Comment: Do you have the same APIs enabled in both projects?

Comment: Yes, I finally got it sorted though, I'll update with the answer later today.

Comment: Thanks! If the final answer is not similar to this answer, could you please post it and accept your own answer? So, the community can easily identify the root cause of this issue.